# Why was the movement for Austro-German unity less successful than that of Italian unity?

Tags: 20th-century, europe, germany, austria

Primarily, I am looking at the differences between say, the movements for German unity and that of Italian nationalists.

The record shows that the people of Austria had accepted without much resistance their unification with Nazi Germany during the "Anschluss" (closing) of 1938. Yet other unification efforts before and after the Anschluss failed.

Considering the fact that almost all countries of Europe are organized on a linguistic basis, why did the movements for Austro-German unity fail?

Comment: Probably because [the last time they tried it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anschluss), it didn't work out... :/

Comment: @YannisRizos But it was not really a failure. The failure was the war, not the process of unification itself.

Comment: Certainly, but it kinda left some (emotional, political, etc) baggage which probably explains why Austrians couldn't care less about unification with Germany nowadays.

Comment: I have improved the question, and nominate it for reopening.

Comment: I support reopening this question. What I'm puzzled though, is what other German-Austrian unification efforts after the "Anschluss" @Arani had in mind, for I am not aware of any serious ones (except for common membership of both countries in the EU).

Comment: And BTW, don't forget the Swiss: its German part is the largest inside this (admittedly small) country :)

Comment: @Drux According to Wikipedia, the Freedom Party of Austria had many people who claimed to be German nationalists, but the party was never able to attract a large number of votes using this plank. I was referring to their effort.

Comment: @Arani I can assure you that their efforts (on unification, i.e.) never came close to be taken seriously by anyone, perhaps not even by themselves. They have to navigate a very odd course indeed: claiming German nationalism (due to their historic legacy) as well as Austrian nationalism (whatever that may amount to exactly; because this is what gets them protest votes from those who suffer from globalization and economic integration) at the same time: IMO it's just one brand of populism.

Comment: @Drux Did not know about the Swiss bit. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: It's unfortunate that this question is closed. There actually is a simple reason: Hungary. When Germany was formed in 1870, Austria also included Hungary, all the way to today's Ukraine. After Austria lost Hungary in WW I, there was renewed interest on Austria's side, but there was no opportunity until 1938. Since that turned out so horribly, the issue simply doesn't arise much any more.

Comment: Switzerland is a completely different situation. Switzerland has been independent for more than 700 years. Switzerland has the opposite problem; they are afraid of getting absorbed by assimilation and losing their national identity. Not unlike Canada.

Answer (score 0):

Austria is prohibited from joining Germany by the Allies of WWII. Austria has no right to do so. It was a condition for the removal of the allied occupation.

Comment: Yes, but after the Allies left in 1955, there was no force that could have imposed those agreements.

Comment: @Arani why do you think there was no such force. Did the Allies (but Soviet Russia) somehow disappear out of history?

Comment: @Drux Simply because the democratic forces are very sensitive to public opinion before waging war, and the people of the Western Allies would surely not support force (just as they accepted unification of East Germany despite the opposition of UK and France).

Comment: Hmmm, you may have a point there, although I was not so much thinking of actual war, but of permanent international sanctions. BTW, I find this an interesting topic (and therefore an interesting question), because before WW2 there were some respectable unification efforts, which by now have been fairly completely covered or disreputed (along with the more wacky ones) by what has happened since.

Comment: If Austria and Germany would now conduct a poll, and the result was "yes for unification", I doubt that the countries which made up the Allies in WW2 would invade them. So such a poll would not fail because of this. It would fail because the current political climate in Germany is centered around not saying absolutely anything which could be turned by someone into an accusation of neo-nazism.